# onSaveInstance outState saving all state with last putString

Tags: android, kotlin, lifecycle, onsaveinstancestate

I was working with Activity

I am using *onSaveInstanceState* lifecycle

when I tried to updating

```
companion object {
    const val EXTRA_INDEX = "extra_index"
    private const val STATE_COMMENT_NAME = ""
    private const val STATE_COMMENT_COMMENT = ""
}
```

on GalleryDetail class with

```
outState.putString(STATE_COMMENT_NAME, tvCommentName.text.toString())
outState.putString(STATE_COMMENT_COMMENT, tvCommentComment.text.toString())
```

within `onSaveInstanceState` lifecycle, `STATE_COMMENT_NAME` was filled by `tvCommentComment.text.toString().trim()`

even when I changed the order, for example

```
outState.putString(STATE_COMMENT_COMMENT, tvCommentName.text.toString().trim())
outState.putString(STATE_COMMENT_NAME, tvCommentComment.text.toString().trim())
```

vice versa, `STATE_COMMENT_COMMENT` will be filled by `tvCommentName.text.toString().trim()`
so, the point is, everything on top of the last putString, it'll be filled by last value of putString

I have do Log the problem, and it show me that the problem is on `onSaveInstanceState` and not on the `onCreate` nor mistype variable to show on UI

so, this is the Log of my code

```
2022-08-09 08:14:57.384 27561-27561/com.dicoding.kelassekolah D/GalleryDetail Bundle: onSaveInstanceState Nice photos!
2022-08-09 08:14:57.384 27561-27561/com.dicoding.kelassekolah D/GalleryDetail Bundle: onSaveInstanceState Nice photos!
2022-08-09 08:14:57.519 27561-27561/com.dicoding.kelassekolah D/GalleryDetail Bundle: savedInstanceState Nice photos!
2022-08-09 08:14:57.519 27561-27561/com.dicoding.kelassekolah D/GalleryDetail Bundle: savedInstanceState Nice photos!
```

`onSaveInstanceState` Gist: https://gist.github.com/amirudev/421d76f671250e015462fa973bb984be

`onCreate if savedInstanceState not null` Gist: https://gist.github.com/amirudev/17d1d74f829de16bf63f672316e3beb6

Comment: `EditText` already saves and restores it's state automatically when you have an `android:id`. What makes you think you need to save those values manually?

Comment: oh, sorry, I use it for TextView actually, I need want to make the value not missing even when I rotating screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put these `STATE_COMMENT_NAME` and `STATE_COMMENT_COMMENT` values not identical to each other:

```
companion object {
    const val EXTRA_INDEX = "extra_index"
    private const val STATE_COMMENT_NAME = "stateCommentName"
    private const val STATE_COMMENT_COMMENT = "stateCommentComment"
}
```

If they are the same (ex. `""`), they are identical.